# Generating colors for heat map when the variance is high

Tags: javascript, colors, heatmap

So I have a JSON array with contains country code and hits from that country which looks something like

```
{c_code: "sg", count: 513}
{c_code: "bg", count: 198}
{c_code: "ua", count: 4463}
....
....
```

I wanted to get color codes for each country in this array based on hits and RGB color range. So I found one algorithm which does this and looks like

```
let max = 0,
    min = Number.MAX_VALUE,
    startColor = [200, 238, 255],
    endColor = [45, 100, 145],
    colors = {},
    hex;

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {

    if (parseFloat(data[i].count) > max) {
        max = parseFloat(data[i].count);
    }
    if (parseFloat(data[i].count) < min) {
        min = parseFloat(data[i].count);
    }
}
console.log(max, min);

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    if (data[i].count > 0) {
        colors[data[i].c_code] = '#';

        for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            hex = Math.round(startColor[j] +
                (endColor[j] -
                    startColor[j]) *
                (parseFloat(data[i].count - min) / (max - min))).toString(16);

            if (hex.length === 1) {
                hex = '0' + hex;
            }

            colors[data[i].c_code] += (hex.length === 1 ? '0' : '') + hex;
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem I am facing is that in my array one country has huge hits compared to other countries (15 Times greater than second largest) as a result of that, colors of rest of the counties looks very much similar. Is there any way to fix this? Is there any better algorithm than the above which can be used to generate the heat map?